# The search fails on some wildcard-tag-searches

Tags: bug, tags, search, architecture

Trying to the search for [`[*-s] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*-s%5D+is%3Aq) fails to yield *any* result, despite the tag [strcat-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strcat-s) having seven questions.

If one leaves off the operator (searching for `[*-s]`), the search implodes and redirects to the all-questions-page.

Comment: Wildcard searches do require [at least four characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a*) in order to be performed. Though a search for `[*cat-s] is:q` still doesn't connect to that tag, even though a search for just `[*cat-s]` does. Looks like the hyphen might break it when it's not a tag-only search.

Comment: Interesting, so part is by design, but the rest is genuine bug... good thing I gave both searches I couldn't do. BTW: Why *at least four characters*, instead of *matching at most n tags*?